# SMPlayer shows no picture for xvid videos, works for h.264 videos

Tags: video, smplayer, vdpau

When I try to play an vxid video with SMPlayer, I can only hear sound, but see no picture. To be more precise, I'm seeing a black picture through the entire video. I'm using SMPlayer 15.11.0 on Kubuntu 16.04. h.264 videos will play just fine. I'm using VDPAU for the video output. When I try to open an vxid video, SMPlayer uses `/usr/bin/mpv` for playback and calls mpv like you can see in the following example:

```
/usr/bin/mpv --no-config --no-quiet --terminal --no-msg-color --input-file=/dev/stdin --no-fs --vd-lavc-threads=7 --hwdec=vdpau --sub-auto=fuzzy --vo=vdpau --ao=alsa:device=[hw:2,0] --no-input-default-bindings --input-x11-keyboard=no --no-input-cursor --cursor-autohide=no --no-keepaspect --wid=117440904 --monitorpixelaspect=1 --osd-scale=1 --sub-ass --embeddedfonts --ass-line-spacing=0 --sub-scale=1.2 --sub-text-font=Fira Sans --sub-text-color=#ffffff --sub-text-shadow-color=#000000 --sub-text-border-color=#000000 --sub-text-border-size=2.5 --sub-text-shadow-offset=5 --ass-force-style=PlayResX=512,PlayResY=320,Name=Default,Fontname=Fira Sans,Fontsize=10,PrimaryColour=&H00ffffff,BackColour=&H00000000,OutlineColour=&H00000000,Bold=0,Italic=0,Alignment=2,BorderStyle=1,Outline=1,Shadow=2,MarginL=20,MarginR=20,MarginV=8 --sub-codepage=utf8:ISO-8859-1 --vid=1 --aid=1 --sub-pos=100 --volume=62 --cache=2048 --osd-level=0 --audio-channels=2 --af-add=scaletempo --af-add=equalizer=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0 --softvol=yes --softvol-max=100 --ytdl=no --term-playing-msg=MPV_VERSION=${=mpv-version:} INFO_VIDEO_WIDTH=${=width} INFO_VIDEO_HEIGHT=${=height} INFO_VIDEO_ASPECT=${=video-aspect} INFO_VIDEO_FPS=${=fps} INFO_VIDEO_FORMAT=${=video-format} INFO_VIDEO_CODEC=${=video-codec} INFO_AUDIO_FORMAT=${=audio-codec-name:${=audio-format}} INFO_AUDIO_CODEC=${=audio-codec} INFO_AUDIO_RATE=${=audio-params/samplerate:${=audio-samplerate}} INFO_AUDIO_NCH=${=audio-params/channel-count:${=audio-channels}} INFO_LENGTH=${=duration:${=length}} INFO_DEMUXER=${=demuxer} INFO_TITLES=${=disc-titles} INFO_CHAPTERS=${=chapters} INFO_TRACKS_COUNT=${=track-list/count} METADATA_TITLE=${metadata/by-key/title:} METADATA_ARTIST=${metadata/by-key/artist:} METADATA_ALBUM=${metadata/by-key/album:} METADATA_GENRE=${metadata/by-key/genre:} METADATA_DATE=${metadata/by-key/date:} METADATA_TRACK=${metadata/by-key/track:} METADATA_COPYRIGHT=${metadata/by-key/copyright:} INFO_MEDIA_TITLE=${=media-title:}  --term-status-msg=STATUS: ${=time-pos} / ${=duration:${=length:0}} P: ${=pause} B: ${=paused-for-cache} I: ${=core-idle} /home/user/video/test_xvid_video.avi
```

If I manually call `/usr/bin/mpv` to open the same video file, the picture will be displayed correctly. Does anyone see a possible reason why I can't see the picture correctly, and ideally what I would need to change? Your help would be appreciated.

Edit: Perhaps [this topic](http://forum.smplayer.info/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=8938) describes the same issue, but I'm not sure. I might try to install an earlier driver for my nvidia graphics adapter. If that will solve the problem, I'll let you know.

Comment: If you have solved it, please post an answer instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: As indicated in [this
topic](http://forum.smplayer.info/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=8938), the problem
was related to the nvidia driver which I was using. I was using the most
recent version from the [graphics drivers
PPA](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)
(currently 384.69). I downgraded to the latest official version which is
supplied by the same PPA (currently 381.22) and the problem is gone.